# Getting a cumulative count of rows in each column excluding NAs in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is structured as follows:

```
structure(list(CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A1Y = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A1Z = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A2Y = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A2Z = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A3Y = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A3Z = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A4Y = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A4Z = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A5Y = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A5Z = c(1.07, 0.41, 0.87, 1.21, 0.99, 0.77, 
0.73, 0.77, 0.61, 0.89), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A6Y = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A6Z = c(NA, 
NA, 0.92, 0.64, 0.63, 0.48, 0.17, 0.28, 0.32, 0.64), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A7Y = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A7Z = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A8Y = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c("1812", "1813", 
"1814", "1815", "1816", "1817", "1818", "1819", "1820", "1821"
), class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like to do is, for each column, get the cumulative count of the number of rows excluding NAs (it's necessary to leave the NAs in at this point).

I've tried the following (where `test` is the dataframe above):

```
test_count = cumsum(colSums(!is.na(test)))
```

But this seems to be continuing the count across columns, whereas I need a unique cumulative count of the number of rows in each column, so that the result is a dataframe that looks like (this is for visual reference only, the numbers are made up):

```
Row.Name    CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A1Y    CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A2Y
  1812              0                      0
  1813              0                      1
  1814              1                      2
```

...indicating that the original dataframe (`test`) had NAs in the first two rows of columns CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A1Y, and an NA in the first row of the column CT.CW.QA.RWL.H1A2Y (again, this hypothetical doesn't represent the values in the data above, it's just to illustrate the structure of what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the column with `lapply`, convert to logical, do the `cumsum` and assign the output back to the original or a copy of the original object.  Make sure to use `[]` to preserve the attributes

```
test1 <- test
test1[] <- lapply(test, function(x) cumsum(!is.na(x)))
```

-output

```
head(test1)
     CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A1Y CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A1Z CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A2Y CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A2Z CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A3Y CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A3Z CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A4Y
1812                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
1813                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
1814                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
1815                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
1816                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
1817                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
     CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A4Z CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A5Y CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A5Z CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A6Y CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A6Z CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A7Y CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A7Z
1812                  0                  0                  1                  0                  0                  0                  0
1813                  0                  0                  2                  0                  0                  0                  0
1814                  0                  0                  3                  0                  1                  0                  0
1815                  0                  0                  4                  0                  2                  0                  0
1816                  0                  0                  5                  0                  3                  0                  0
1817                  0                  0                  6                  0                  4                  0                  0
     CT_CW.QA.RWL.H1A8Y
1812                  0
1813                  0
1814                  0
1815                  0
1816                  0
1817                  0
....
```

---

There is a `colCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
test1[] <- colCumsums(!is.na(test))
```

---

The issue with `cumsum` returning a vector is because `colSums` is a single `vector` of one observation per each column, and `cumsum` on it returns the cumulative sum of column sums instead of cumulative sum inside each column

Comment: Ah, yes. I was almost there. Although, this doesn't seem to preserve the row names. Is there a way to keep those?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either. The update produces a large list where each item seems to correspond to the cumulative count of the columns, again without the row names

Comment: @BenLockwood I get the rownames as well.  Updated the values I am getting

Comment: @BenLockwood I am not sure what you expect as output.  I find your dummy expected to be similar

Comment: My mistake, I had an error in my code. It's working perfectly now, much appreciated